# compare rows between 2 sheets in excel using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have 2 sheets in excel and I am trying to compare by row using VBA.

I did some searching but can only find help comparing sheets and not by row.

I need to check row 1 of sheet A against all rows of sheet B, then row 2 of sheet A etc then delete duplicates so I am left with new or updated rows.

Comment: Could you show us the code that you tried?

Answer (score 0):

You need a procedure like this:

```
Sub cleanUp()

Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim k As Long

Dim LastRowA As Long
Dim LastRowB As Long
Dim endA As Long
Dim endB As Long

Dim rowMatch As Boolean

LastRowA = Sheets("A").UsedRange.Rows.Count
For i = 1 To LastRowA
    endA = Sheets("A").Cells(i, Sheets("A").Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    LastRowB = Sheets("B").UsedRange.Rows.Count
    For j = 1 To LastRowB
        rowMatch = True
        endB = Sheets("B").Cells(j, Sheets("B").Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        If endA <> endB Then
            rowMatch = False
        Else
            k = 1
            While rowMatch And k <= endA
                If Sheets("A").Cells(i, k).Value <> Sheets("B").Cells(j, k).Value Then rowMatch = False
                k = k + 1
            Wend
        End If
        If rowMatch Then Sheets("B").Rows(j).Delete
    Next j
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Can you explain all that code further? What does it do? Keep in mind that others should be able to learn from your answer

Comment: In a first loop, the code goes down all rows of sheet A. "i" is the index of the current row of sheet A. Each row has a last cell with a value. The index of this last cell is stored in the variable "endA". Inside of this first loop, a second loop is done going down all rows of sheet B with "j" being the row index. If the current row lengths are equal, every cell is compared between sheet A and sheet B. This is done in the last nested loop with index "k". Only in case of a match, the row on sheet B is deleted.